# How to iterate a table with watir when no html element has identifiers

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have an html table which has a table with unequal number of columns for each row. The table and cells/columns have no identifiers such as id, name, class etc. How do I iterate over such a table and print it in tabular form ? I am using ruby 1.8 for now.

**Html -**

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Student Info</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Age:</td> <td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Home:</td> <td>251 Palm Avenue</td></tr>

    <tr><td>City:</td>  <td>New York</td></tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2">Parent Info</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Parent Phone:</td>    <td>231-1234-123</td></tr>
    <tr><td>More parent info</td>   <td><a href="http://www.school.com>school</a><br></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Ruby code -**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

url = "url has tables with no identifiable attributes. Just a table tag"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto url

browser.table.trs.each do |tr|
    tr.each do |td|
        puts td.to_s
    end
end
```

**Trace -**

```
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:553:in `method_missing': undefined method `each' for #<Watir::TableRow:0x517bf9c> (NoMethodError)
        from tables.rb:10
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:29:in `each'
        from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:29:in `each'
        from tables.rb:9
```

Comment: What did you want to get as an output? If you just want to address the exception, it should be `tr.tds.each do |td|` - ie you want to do `each` on the td collection rather than the row.

Comment: @JustinKo - I wanted to see the table text in the console output. I was trying to get the answer myself, but I could not understand the online documentation. How do I learn to read and understand the documentation ? Example for trs - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/TableRowCollection

Comment: I decent way to do this is by finding some unique text in the headers or in the caption or something of the desired table and then using `.parent` to get the parent `<table>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the table, and send it to a file (or variable) iterating over the rows and placing a tab between the  elements

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto url

f = File.new('table.txt',  'w+')

t = browser.table

t.trs.each do |trd|
  trd.tds.each do |td|
    f.print "#{td.text}\t"
  end
  f.print "\n"
end

f.close
```

EDIT** in answer to the question in the comments:

Well, don't be hard on yourself, I don't think the documentation is beginner friendly. I had to extrapolate from what Justin_Ko said and the docs to see that  was referenced by `tr` and the collection of  was ref'd by `trs`. The thing to remember is that those collections, and most everything returned by the WATIR methods are objects, but they might no behave like you think. `trs` is an Enumerator, but it only returns objects, not the text of the row itself. Same with `td`. That's why I had to iterate through the collection of rows then iterate through each row's `td` objects, then call `.text` on that object. Think about WATIR this way, you can reference anything by a class or identifier, or as in this case just by HTML elements. `browser` reads everything in the page, from there you can target any element(s) using the WATIR methods.

The cheat sheet is very handy:

https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Comment: Thanks !!! I was trying to get the answer myself, but I could not understand the online documentation. How do I learn to read and understand the documentation ? Example for trs - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/TableRowCollection

Comment: I would also go through the tutorial https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Tutorial